# Shoulda Matcher can't find foreign ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I have a test like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
  it { should have_many(:assignments) }
  it { should have_many(:roles).through(:assignments) }
end
```

Which returns this error:

```
Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:assignments) }
       Expected User to have a has_many association called assignments (Assignment does not have a user_id foreign key.)
```

However my schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "assignments", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "role_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

My models look like this:

`user.rb`

```
require 'role_model'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 8 }

  include RoleModel
  roles_attribute :roles_mask
  roles :admin, :super_admin, :user
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments 

end
```

here is `assignment.rb`

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed nothing and the error simply went away a day later.  I'm guessing something went out of sync for a bit but it's ok now.

Answer (score 3):

Try your migration with the more-standard "references" (instead of just integer):

```
create_table "assignments", force: true do |t|
  t.references  "user", index: true
  t.integer  "role_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Alternatively are you double-triple sure you've run your migrations?
Sometimes you need to run them for your tests too (if you're running an individual rspec spec rather than running all of them using rake). if in doubt: `rake db:test:prepare`